# How do I link to a missing dylib in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, postgis

I am a little nervous to mess with anything in the terminal because of my small amount of experience of getting anything right on the first try. Which is why I'm asking.

I'm trying to run shp2pgsql with fresh install of OSX Mavericks. I've installed Postgres 9.3 v2.1.0-2 with PostGIS 2.1.

The error I'm getting is:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I've looked at 
http://librelist.com/browser//homebrew/2013/5/15/missing-dylib-files/#85200742c00af0a239140b02f860d987 which suggests that `brew install gettext`.  This has installed `libintl.8.dylib` at:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.3.1/lib/libintl.8.dylib
```

I have found some resources on how to make symbolic (?) links, but I'm unsure if this is the appropriate solution or even how to do it in this specific case since `shp2pgsql` is referencing:

`@loader_path/../lib/libintl.8.dylib`

Thank you!

-Nicholas

Comment: Well, it's certainly part of the gettext libraries. Presumably you have a different version on your system - the libintl.dylib is probably a symlink to the actual versioned library. Can't advise on OSX although I've seen lots of people with assorted PG problems on the new Mavericks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "loader" is `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql`. That makes dyld's notion of the `@loader_path` equal to `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin`. Substituting that into the library reference transforms `@loader_path/../lib/libintl.8.dylib` to `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/../lib/libintl.8.dylib`. Simplifying that, we get `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libintl.8.dylib`. So that's where Postgres apparently expects its `libintl` library to be located.

If it's not there, that suggests the Postgres install is broken. You'd have to take that up with whoever provided it.

It's *possible* that you can work around this by setting a dyld environment variable. For example, you could try `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` before invoking Postgres. However, this will cause Postgres to use a different library than it was linked against, which isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: Hi Ken!  Thank you so much for your answer about the path...  I ended up copying the libintl.8.dylib file to the path were shp2pgsql was expecting it.  Works now.  Thank you!

There have been a couple of other issues with the enterprise db installer of postgres and postgis on osx 10.9... do you think I should report them?

Comment: Yes, you should probably report this to people bundling PostreSQL for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recompile `shp2pgsql` program. As you upgraded your system and libraries, you have now to recompile your program to those new libraries.

Comment: I installed Mavericks first, then postgres & postgis.  I tried re-installing postgis... but that didn't fix the issue.  I'm not sure how to recompile something.

Comment: Oh, you are not using PostgreSQL installed through homebrew, but an independent one.